# How to display a default value from the database into a jsp/html?

Tags: java, database, jsp

I'm currently working on a 'twitter-like' project and we're provided with the EER Diagram with table account with a "biography" column with default value "No Description Yet". I like to display the value in my profile interface.

I need to make this work first before moving on to the "edit profile" section.

I can post my current codes (servlet, jsp, DAO, etc) if you need them. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to display default value if there is null value in database ? Can you post your files ?

Comment: the biography is not null in the database since it has a default value of "No Description Yet". I want to display the "No Description Yet" in the profile interface. what exact file do you need?

Comment: `profile interface` How do you make the default value for the interface . Do you want to show your user in the front-end ?